Father and son both warders
Father and his adult son both are employed as guards in prison. They lived together without wife/mother. I remember the funny detail: they both pay the same girl/prostitute for sex.
The main actor who plays the father could be Tommy Lee Jones or similar looking actor.

Can you remember any more details? What language was the film? Location? Any lines or quotes from the movie? Approximate year?

I'm pretty sure that it's Monster's Ball.
Billy Bob Thornton and Heath Ledger play father and son who both work as correction officers. They also both visit the same prostitute.

exactlly, thx! :)
